# Как сделать один "слушатель" для разных EditText,

Tags: java, android

Есть два EditText etDay и etMonth.
Есть два слушателя для каждого свой:

```
etDay.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length() == 2){
      if (s2i(String.valueOf(s),1) < 32) etMonth.requestFocus();
        else etDay.setText("");
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
});

etMonth.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  if (s.length() == 2){
    if (s2i(String.valueOf(s),1) < 13) etYear.requestFocus();
      else etMonth.setText("");
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
});
```

Надо сделать один слушатель используя конструкцию:

```
switch (view.getId()){
  case R.id.etDay: break;
  case R.id.etMonth: break;
  default:
}
```

Comment: вот здесь хитрое решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext/4283532

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях я просто переопределяю стандартный TextWatcher([Клик](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172024/7334652)). Иных элегантных решений я не встречал.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятны ваши цели, но я делал следующим образом, если у меня есть одинаковые действия для разных editText:

и так, идея в следующем, создаём свой EditText, наследуясь от стандартного, в нём переопределяем TextWatcher и выполняем в нём те действия которые вам нужны. Используем в xml переопределённый EditText. В xml: `<your_package.custom_ui.CustomEditText ... />`. Профит!

Пункт два: если вы хотите что бы он выполнял ещё какие либо действия, но задавать их снаружи, делаем слушатель (интерфейс) и вызываем его метод в TextWatchere в том месте, где хотите чтобы он выполнился (до или после ваших основных манипуляций). Снаружи же, берёте созданный вами интерфейс и подпихиваете ему всё что вам нравится. Возможно не самое изящное решение, но вполне рабочее.

Если снаружи решите переопределить интерфейс TextWatcher-a внутренний использоваться не будет.

```kotlin
class CustomEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyle: Int = R.style.Widget_AppCompat_EditText_Custom,
defStyleRes: Int = R.style.Widget_AppCompat_EditText_Custom
) : EditText(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {

private var onTextChangedListener: OnTextChangedListener? = null
fun setOnTextChangedListener(onTextChangedListener: OnTextChangedListener) {
    this.onTextChangedListener = onTextChangedListener
}

init {
    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            validation(s)
            onTextChangedListener?.onTextChangedListener(s)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }
    })
}

private fun validation(s: Editable) {
    //универсальный валидатор
}

interface OnTextChangedListener {
    fun onTextChangedListener(s: Editable?)
}
}


etCustom.setOnTextChangedListener(object : CustomEditText.OnTextChangedListener {
        override fun onTextChangedListener(s: Editable?) {
            //дополнительный валидатор
        }
    })
```

P.S. готовое решение есть только под Kotlin, но в принципе, разницы особой нет.

Comment: Цель была одна - сократить код, чтобы не писать для каждого TextEdit свои "слушатели", но похоже это был самый простой вариант.